# Is it possible to merge similar contents in a single array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => C
        [2] => B
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => A
        [2] => C
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => C
        [2] => A
    )
)
```

The contents in each array are similar, is it possible to merger them and have one single array as below?

```
  Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C
    )
)
```

Is there a php function to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
<?php
$a = array(
  array('A', 'B', 'C'),
  array('A', 'C', 'B'),
  array('B', 'A', 'C'),
  array('B', 'C', 'A')
);
$c = array();
foreach ($a as $b) {
  if (! empty($b)) {
    foreach ($b as $d) {
      $c[] = $d;
    }
  }
}
$c = array_unique($c);
echo '<pre>';print_r($c);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

```
array_unique (call_user_func_array ('array_merge', $yourArray));
```

You don't need to create custom function, here is a working example:

```
$a = array(
 array('a','b','c'), array('b','c','a'), array('a','c','b')
);

$x = array_unique (call_user_func_array ('array_merge', $a));
var_dump($x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below :

```
$final = $newArr = array();
foreach ($a as $val) {
    foreach ($val as $value)
    $newArr[] = $value;    
}
$final = array_unique($newArr);
print_r($final);
```